# Encrypt Files Before Sending To Bittorrent Sync

Tags: backup, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt files before being sent to Bittorrent sync, either via a plugin, or by encrypting the files first?

Also do you trust Bittorrent Sync's encryption?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the proper place for it, but you certainly can encrypt files before moving them into a folder, for example with [CryptSync](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CryptSync.html) (No affiliation, but open-source and based on 7zip)

as for trusting Bittorrent Sync's encryption, not in particular (I prefer open-source stuff), but I feel reasonably safe using it since it can be configured to be local-only, and securing local connections is certainly doable.

edit: now that Sync is out of beta, getting it to work in a local-only way is exceedingly tedious and difficult, and I  can no longer recommend it